# Why is apache writing two access log outputs per request?

Tags: php, apache-2.4, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

We are currently running a apache2/mod-php site on docker, deployed to google kubernetes. In order to leverage the severity level filtering of google cloud logging I've created a `LogFormat` in our apache.conf that writes the logs output as structured JSON. Now I'm seeing two access log outputs in our logs. 1 is the correctly formatted CustomLog and the other seems to be a default access log of some sort.

Here's the apache conf:

```
  1 LogLevel info
  2 
  3 LogFormat "{\"message\": \"%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t '%r' %>s %b '%{Referer}i' '%{User-Agent}i'\", \"severity\": \"INFO\"}" common
  4 CustomLog /dev/stderr common
  5 
  6 
  7 ErrorLogFormat "{\"message\": \"[%t] [%l] [pid %P] %F: %E: [client %a] %M\", \"severity\": \"ERROR\"}"
  8 ErrorLog /dev/stderr
  9 
 10 <VirtualHost *:80>
 11   ServerName myhost.com
 12   ServerAlias myhost.com
 13   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public/
 14 
 15   <Directory />
 16     AllowOverride All
 17     Order allow,deny
 18     Allow from all
 19 
 20     RewriteEngine on
 21     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 22     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 23     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
 24   </Directory>
 25 
 26   <Directory ~ "\.svn">
 27     Order allow,deny
 28     Deny from all
 29   </Directory>
 30 
 31   <Directory ~ "\.git">
 32     Order allow,deny
 33     Deny from all
 34   </Directory>
 35 
 36   RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
 37   RemoteIPTrustedProxy 10.0.0.0/24
 38 
 39 </VirtualHost>
```

My error logs and info logs are showing up correctly in google cloud storage. However I keep seeing other access log entries.

Samples:

**This log should not show up**

```
::1 - - [13/May/2016:23:32:06 +0000] "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1" 404 2970 "-" "Sysdig Agent/1.0"
```

**This log should show up**

```
{"message": "- - - [13/May/2016:23:32:06 +0000] 'GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1' 404 2720 '-' 'Sysdig Agent/1.0'", "severity": "INFO"}
```

I've tried a number of different configurations and none of them seem to fix the problem. Any idea where this unwanted access log output is coming from?

Comment: Do you have any other `CustomLog` directive in any other config file? As noted in [Access Log documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#accesslog), "Multiple access logs can be created simply by specifying multiple CustomLog directives in the configuration file."

Comment: We're loading 1 apache.conf file in our Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like this version of php-apache for docker: `FROM php:5.5-apache` sends a custom log output to the process out. This makes sense as you would want `docker log` to actually output something when run.

To remedy this issue we will comment out the following lines:

```
45 LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
46 LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
47 LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
48 LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
49 LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
50 
#51 CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 combined
```